# Chrome Extension once disabled can't be enabled until reinstall

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I created a chrome extension, which works fine when it is unpacked. Whether in Normal mode and Incognito mode too.
But when I pack the extension using "Pack Extension" feature of Chrome to pack the extension. Produced crx (packed extension) is once gets installed on Chrome, but when either

1. I disable the extension, or
2. Click on option "Allow in Incognito" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwrrs.png

Then, the Extension never gets activated until I remove the extension from chrome and reinstall.
On clicking the **Enable** checkbox it seems that it is activated but when you refresh the page, you'll see that extension is still deactivated, https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMPCz.png

Any resolutions?

**Edit:**
I Saw the console:
Here is the error on clicking the checkbox:

**Unchecked runtime.lastError while running management.setEnabled: Extension bdkngoljejekigejmcekcpghahpgljop cannot be modified by user.reportIfUnchecked @ extensions::lastError:133handleResponse @ extensions::sendRequest:78**

[image: a busy cat]

Menifest:

```
{
    "name": "TEST MAIN",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "TEST MAIN",
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "Manipulate DOM",
        "icons": ["images/icon.png"],
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
            "js": [ "js/jquery.min.js", "js/main.js" ],
            "css" : ["all.css"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/main.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Quick reminder that Chrome is [not supposed to work with self-packed extensions anymore](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html).

Comment: then how to pack an extension and why the option is available to developers to confuse them?

Comment: Becuase it's valid for Chrome Apps, it's valid for enterprise deployment of extensions, and it's still valid for Linux, I think. You should submit your extension to Chrome Web Store; you can do it "unlisted" if it's a private extension.

Comment: I already have some extensions from some websites (which are not on chrome app store) but they don't 
have such nature, and also works on Incognito mode.

Comment: They are 3rd party extensions. not mine :)

Comment: the unchecked lastError warning is not the problem. post your manifest.

Comment: updated in question.

Comment: Your `browser_action.icons` key is invalid, but I doubt it's the source of your problem.

Comment: what it should be then?